# Joomla and PHP Smarty Framework

Tags: php, joomla, smarty

I have a website which goes on Joomla 3 and PHP Smarty Framework (in which the component is written)

It is Auction site and I currently have some issues with the Smarty...

Here's the deal - When user is logged on, the site shows all his bids, in the bid history, marked as orange.

I would like the site to show marked bid in orange ONLY if you have the highest bid. If not - nothing...

Here is the excerpt from that part of the code:

```
{if $bid->userid==$userid}
{assign var="tr_class" value="auction_bids_mybid1"}
<a name = 'mybid' id = 'mybid'></a>
{/if}
```

This uses the variables from the GetBestMethod from some other file:

```
        public function GetBestBid($userid = FALSE)

    {



        $db = JFactory::getDbo();



        $query = "SELECT * FROM #__bids AS b WHERE auction_id='$this->id' " . ($userid ? (' AND userid=' . $userid) : '') . "  ORDER BY bid_price DESC";

        $db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);



        $res = $db->loadObject();



        if (!$res) {

            $query = "SELECT * FROM `#__bids` AS `b` WHERE `auction_id`='$this->id'  ORDER BY                         `bid_price` DESC";

            $db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);

            $res = $db->loadObject();

        }



        return $res;

    }
```

So, basically long story short:

*if current user has the highest bid then mark the bid else nothing.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: In order to mark only the highest (top) bid you have to just add this:

```
{if $bid->userid==$userid && $smarty.foreach.bids.index == 0}
```

That's it ;)